# Can not read property length of undefined in React-Native/VirtualizedSectionList.js

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I was trying to modify the state of my react-native app; however, after the modification I get the following error message.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db0CJ.png)

I have stack traced it to line 230 in the VirtualizedSectionList of react native. I am not sure what exactly would be causing the error. A potential solution may be resetting my react-native store, but I could not figure out how to do that. Here is my current redux store code.

```js
'use strict';


import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const logger = store => next => action => {
 if(typeof action === 'function') console.log('dispatching a function');
 else console.log('dispatching', action);
 let result = next(action);
 console.log('next state', store.getState());
 return result;
}

let middlewares = [
 logger,
 thunk
];

let createAppStore = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore);


export default function configureStore(onComplete: ()=>void){
 const store = autoRehydrate()(createAppStore)(reducers);
 let opt = {
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  transform: [],
  blacklist: ['nav','util']
 };
 persistStore(store, opt, onComplete);
 return store;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem an issue with store, i think it is there where you are using ur states may be or something else, if you upload other code than i can check it but i don't think this error is due to store.

Comment: Yea it ended up being an error with how rows were being created. Thanks for trying to help.